# Unable to update fields value through Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I recorded jmeter  script to update Machine Brand field 'MB' to 'M' on page(HD Treatment Flowsheet). Screenshot is Attached. Machine Brand parameter name is 'txtMachine'.

Now i executed this script. Now to validate result login into application and navigate to this page(HD Treatment Flowsheet) and found this field Machine Brand value is not updated. 
To debug I checked View Result Tree Listner and also there in Request and Response data its value is 'M' means updated value. But in application it is not showing updated value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pTFR.png

Kindly help what is reason value is not updated.

HTTP Request:

Method: POST
Path: /_/HDTreatmentFlowSheet.aspx
Content Encoding: utf-8
Parameter Name: txtMachine
Value: M
URL Encode: No
Content Type: text/plan
Include Equlas: yes

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 reasons:

1. Request which is being sent by JMeter is not inline with the request, sent by the real browser, double check that the browser and JMeter are sending exactly the same requests using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
2. It might be the case of missing or not proper [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/), for example [ASP.NET ViewState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972976(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

It is hard to say what's wrong without seeing full network dumps including full request body and [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) from the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and JMeter, hopefully you will be able to figure that out yourself, if not - find a way to share the requests with us (i.e. as .har file from the browser and as XML file from JMeter)